# State stays the same when using event listeners

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

https://codesandbox.io/s/state-shenanigans-mifyg

This code example is a bit un-orthodox, but it still puzzles me so I decided to form it into a question.

Please open the link above and play with the example. Keep the console open as well.

When the form changes I'm calling console.log, passing it the state. As you can see when changing the *question* it logs the right value (the new question with the existing answer).

But if you then change the answer you find that the *old* question is logged out with the new answer.

I guess it has something to do with closures, but I couldn't figure it out.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function Faq({ onChange, data }) {
  const questionRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();
  const answerRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (questionRef.current) {
      questionRef.current.addEventListener("keydown", (e: any) => {
        onChange({ ...data, question: e.target.value });
      });
    }

    if (answerRef.current) {
      answerRef.current.addEventListener("keydown", (e: any) => {
        onChange({ ...data, answer: e.target.value });
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={questionRef} type="text" defaultValue={data.question} />
      <input ref={answerRef} type="text" defaultValue={data.answer} />
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const [faq, setFaq] = React.useState({
    id: "1",
    question: "I am a question?",
    answer: "I am the answer!"
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(faq);
  }, [faq]);
  return <Faq data={faq} onChange={setFaq} />;
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "old" and "new" question, since there's only one question. In any case, you don't have to use DOM references and manual EvenListeners in React. React was invented to handle that kind of stuff for you!

```
function Faq({ onChange, data }) {

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log("the new value is")
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" defaultValue={data.question} />
      <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" defaultValue={data.answer} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Of course, but I need it for a specific reason and I couldn't understand why react behaves that way

Answer (score 0):

You will need to refresh the data:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function Faq({ onChange, data }) {
  const questionRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();
  const answerRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (questionRef.current) {
      questionRef.current.addEventListener("keydown", (e: any) => {
        onChange({ ...data, question: e.target.value });
        data.question = e.target.value;
      });
    }

    if (answerRef.current) {
      answerRef.current.addEventListener("keydown", (e: any) => {
        onChange({ ...data, answer: e.target.value });
        data.answer = e.target.value;
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={questionRef} type="text" defaultValue={data.question} />
      <input ref={answerRef} type="text" defaultValue={data.answer} />
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const [faq, setFaq] = React.useState({
    id: "1",
    question: "I am a question?",
    answer: "I am the answer!"
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(faq);
  }, [faq]);
  return <Faq data={faq} onChange={setFaq} />;
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/state-shenanigans-kupjj

Comment: Isn't `onChange={setFaq}` in charge of updating the data? Why do I need to be explicit about it?

Comment: @dutzi I don't know, never worked with ReactJS, but played around with your script, until it worked.